# как реализовать работу с различными параметрами в операторе присваивания

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17, агрегация

```
//template<Typename T>
class Data { // в общем перегружаю оператор присвоения
public:
    void processing(){}
    void print(){}
private:
};
// С++17, как заморочится так что бы работать с объектом Data
// перегрузив оператор присвоения
// может как можно через агрегирование сделать, другую шаблонную
// структурку


int main() {
    Data data;// возможно ли это

    data = 999;
    data.print(); // 999
    data.processing(); 

    int* value = new int(888); //888
    data = value;
    data.print();
    data.processing();

    data = std::string("Ananas"); 
    data.print();
    data.processing();

    data = 3.14;
    data.print();
    data.processing();
    delete value;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может, через [`variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)?

Comment: Вам надо с помощью оператора присваивания присваивать различные типы `Data`? Сделайте его шаблонным тогда. См. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/operator%3D, например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, так:

```
class Data
{
private:
    template<typename T>
    struct ValueHolder;

    template<>
    struct ValueHolder<void>
    {
        virtual ~ValueHolder() = default;
        virtual void print() = 0;
        virtual void processing() = 0;
    };

    template<typename T>
    struct ValueHolder : ValueHolder<void>
    {
        template<typename U>
        explicit ValueHolder(U&& value) : value(std::forward<U>(value)) {}
        void print() override { std::cout << value << std::endl; }
        void processing() override {}

    private:
        T value;
    };

public:
    void print() { m_holder->print(); }
    void processing() { m_holder->processing(); }

    template<typename T>
    Data& operator=(T&& value)
    {
        m_holder = std::make_unique<ValueHolder<T>>(std::forward<T>(value));
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<ValueHolder<void>> m_holder;
};
```

Пример:

```
int main()
{
    Data data;

    data = 10;
    data.print();

    data = 'c';
    data.print();
}
```

P.S. Я не утруждал себя проверками ошибок и проработкой дизайна, этот пример иллюстрирует только основы [техники](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Type_Erasure), которая позволяет сделать то, что Вы хотите.